# How can I recover grub2 (Fedora) that has been killed by Windows 10 using Fedora-LiveUSB, on Acer laptop?

Tags: fedora, grub2, acer

Windows 10 has killed grub2, how can I recover the grub to access to Fedora again using a Fedora Live USB?, I'm sure that i installed fedora in uefi mode, I had used for some time Fedora in dual boot with Windows, but after some time, the grub2 didn't appear, Windows 10 started directly.

PD: I'm using a laptop, Acer Aspire E-15

Comment: Hi George. If you take a look at the EFI partition, there is a GRUBx64.efi there? If so, you will not need to reinstall grub but only create an entry on your UEFI Menu...

Comment: there is a fedora folder in EFI folder, and there is in 'boot' folder the next files, bootx64.efi,fallback.efi, bootia32.efi, fbia32.efi and fbx64.efi, but there isn't GRUBx64.efi., GRUBX64 file there is in 'fedora' folder. @nwildner

Comment: Booting your Fedora Installation disk in "rescue mode"(take a look at Fedora docs) and creating a new entry with the following command should be enough: `efibootmgr --create --disk /dev/sda --part 2 --loader /EFI/fedora/grubx64.efi --label "Fedora Grub`. But that's weir that there isn't a grubx64.efi file. Maybe Fedora has changed. It's being years that i don't use it :)

Comment: thank you @nwildner I had resolved my problem but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

GRUBx64.efi wasn't deleted on EFI partition, I finded it in fedora folder in EFI partition, I used CMD on Windows 10 and I copied from fedora folder the grub file to boot folder, then I restarted my computer and pressed F2 and I added to UEFI menu the grub file, finally I could access to the grub and I could select fedora OS.